# Return object vector (e.g. list of variables) as character vector in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I would like to return an object vector (e.g. a list of variables) as a character vector in R. This is as close as I've gotten:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- as_tibble(mtcars)

foo <- function (vars) {
  as.character(enexpr(vars))
}

foo(c(hp, drat, wt))
```

I would like this to return `[1] "hp"   "drat" "wt"`  but instead I'm getting `[1] "c"    "hp"   "drat" "wt"`.

The code below works but it seems inelegant (and requires reading in the data):

```
foo <- function (vars) {
  names(select(data, {{ vars }}))
}

foo(c(hp, drat, wt))
```

The application is passing a selection of variables to a paste function so that they can be combined to make a formula.

**Edit:** It goes without saying, this would also obviously work:

```
foo <- function (vars) {
  as.character(enexpr(vars))[-1]
}

foo(c(hp, drat, wt))
```

My feeling though is that there still must be a tidier (pun intended) way of doing this.

Comment: why not use `names(mtcars)`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```r
library(rlang)
foo <- function(...){
  l <- quos(...)
  sapply(l, quo_name)
}

foo(hp, drat, wt)
#>                      
#>   "hp" "drat"   "wt"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This would only work if I don't want to use `...` for something else and if I only have have one set of variables I want to pass. If for example, I'm fitting a particularly complex model, I might have different sets of variables (e.g. predictors, instruments, outcomes, etc) that I want to pass to different places inside my function. I would want to be able to enter these as separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend tidyselect for this sort of things.

```r
foo <- function (data, vars) {
  tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(vars), data)
}

foo(mtcars, c(hp, drat, wt))
#>   hp drat   wt
#>    4    5    6
```

As a bonus you gain all of the tidyselect features:

```r
foo(mtcars, starts_with("d"))
#> disp drat
#>    3    5
```

Note that you have to supply a data frame. This follows the tidyverse principle that unquoted object names can only refer to existing objects.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. And I also love that it retains the tidyselect features. Pulling the names from the object returned by tidyselect gets me to where I was trying to get to:

```
foo <- function (data, vars) {
  x <- tidyselect::eval_select(enquo(vars), data)
  names(x)
}

foo(mtcars, c(hp, drat, wt))
```